Does Avatar: Frontiers of Pandora have infinitely respawning side content, or is it possible to complete all available content between story missions?
When I play games, I like finishing as much of the map as I can between main story quests: enemy bases, puzzles, large battles, collectibles, side quests, and so on, to the point of consulting guides on when certain side objectives become available so I know I shouldn't try to get a side objective I can't get yet. I've done so in both Spider-Man games on PC, Ratchet & Clank, Baldur's Gate 3, the Batman Arkham games, Assassin's Creed Mirage, and so on.
The only games I haven't done this in are games that either have a tremendous or even infinite amount of tedious side quests or collectibles, like Assassin's Creed Valhalla/Odyssey, Far Cry 6 or Skyrim. In games like this, I focus on narratively important side content like the guild storylines or the Order of the Ancients, things that will help me get to the best final ending, after which I stop playing the game entirely.
The question I have is: Does Avatar: Frontiers of Pandora fall under the first category of games that have a finite amount of side content unlocking at a steady pace between side objectives, or is it more of a second category game, where there's a lot of infinitely repeating content that's used for farming EXP or other currency for upgrades?
